# Lakshmi mantra translation

Tags: mantras, translation-request

Can anyone please help me find the English translation for:

> Om Lakshmi Vigan Shri Kamala Dharigan Svaha

I know the overall purpose of the mantra, but cannot find the meanings of several words

Comment: Its NOT a correct mantra! please check

Comment: @commonman If you know the correct mantra with translation then you can write the answer stating "the correct mantra is ....."

Comment: @KrishnaShweta No I dont know,I cd only understand that the words are wrong.Vigan and Dharigan --I cd not decifer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a recent invented "mantra" which does not appear in Sanskrit texts of Shri Kamalatmika or Lakshmi puja. So forget about asking translation for an invented non-sense "mantra". Words seems to be forms of some dialect, not clear which, maybe poor Hindi or Bengali denaturalised words. Having no real links with tradition of Mantra-yana, either not based on existing Sanskrit source texts, is just an example on how "intoxication" occurs in our days due new age and other mixed fake "beliefs". (Personal note:  I found it also online in a published book about How to be reach, which author is near subject very very bad. Common, really ? :)) We invent mantras to sell things? )